# Logitech Casa pop up desk bluetooth pairing problems

Tags: bluetooth

Have a Logitech Casa pop up desk (keyboard and trackpad). Using a Dell XPS 2-in-1 with Ubutnu 20.04. I've also got a Logtech MX keys and MX keys mini which both work fine.

I was having issues getting either the trackpad of keyboard from the Casa set to pair with my computer. For the keyboard, the GIU would just say pairing failed. I did at some stage manage to get a pin code to pop up for the keyboard, but it wouldn't work. The trackpad would pair, but every time I used it the bluetooth would completely crash.

I changed my bluetooth mode from bredr to dual (and le) through sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf which allowed me to actually see they keyboard and trackpad

I swapped over to using bluetoothctl, and was able to pair the keyboard.

However, whenever I pair the trackpad, either with the GUI or bluetoothctl it crashes as soon as I use it.

I'm in somewhat of a bind, as the whole point of the Casa pop up desk is both the trackpad and the keyboard, so if I can't get them both to work i'll have to send it back.

Any help would be appreciated. I much preferred the MX keys' dongle, but sadly neither the Casa nor the MX mini come with dongles anymore, it's all BT.

dmesg output:

```
[25995.079493] input: Casa Touch Mouse as /devices/virtua/misc/uhid/0005:046D:BB00.001B/input/input82
[25995.080217] hid-generic 0005:046D:BB00.001B: input,hidraw2:BLUETOOTH HID v0.18 Mouse [Casa Touch] on c4:23:60:9f:93:7b
[25995.379234] bluetoothd[72174]: segfault at 70 ip 00007f46f2ff5694 sp 00007ffc3a230718 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f46f2f72000+85000]
[25995.379260] Code: 28 00 00 00 75 18 48 81 c4 a8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 5d 41 5c c3 66 90 41 80 64 24 5e df eb cd e8 e3 da f7 ff 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa <8b> 47 70 c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 41 54 49 89 f4 e8 76 e3 f7 ff
```

The output when it crashes from bluetoothctl is:

```
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000a
00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000a/char000b
00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Service Changed
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x4b64)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000a/char000b/desc000d
00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e
0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Device Information
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char000f
00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Manufacturer Name String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0011
00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Model Number String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0013
00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Serial Number String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0015
00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Firmware Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0017
00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Software Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0019
00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
PnP ID
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056
0000fd72-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Unknown
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char0057
fd720001-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char0059
fd720002-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char005b
fd720003-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char005d
fd720004-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char005f
fd720005-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char0061
fd720006-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0063
00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x8461)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0063/char0064
00010001-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x4034)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0063/char0064/desc0066
00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Client Characteristic Configuration
[CHG] Device D3:B1:66:30:DC:36 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device D3:B1:66:30:DC:36 Paired: yes
Agent unregistered
[DEL] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B ben-XPS-13-9310-2-in-1 [default]
[DEL] Primary Service (Handle 0xa290)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000a
00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Generic Attribute Profile
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000a/char000b
00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Service Changed
[DEL] Descriptor (Handle 0x0006)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000a/char000b/desc000d
00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Client Characteristic Configuration
[DEL] Primary Service (Handle 0x0160)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e
0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Device Information
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char000f
00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Manufacturer Name String
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0011
00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Model Number String
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0013
00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Serial Number String
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0015
00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Firmware Revision String
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0017
00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Software Revision String
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service000e/char0019
00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
PnP ID
[DEL] Primary Service (Handle 0x9b60)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056
0000fd72-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Unknown
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char0057
fd720001-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char0059
fd720002-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char005b
fd720003-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char005d
fd720004-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char005f
fd720005-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0056/char0061
fd720006-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Primary Service (Handle 0x78a0)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0063
00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Characteristic (Handle 0x2b00)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0063/char0064
00010001-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Vendor specific
[DEL] Descriptor (Handle 0x0006)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D3_B1_66_30_DC_36/service0063/char0064/desc0066
00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Client Characteristic Configuration
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B Name: ben-XPS-13-9310-2-in-1
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B Alias: BlueZ 5.53
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B Alias: ben-XPS-13-9310-2-in-1
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller C4:23:60:9F:93:7B UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device D3:B1:66:30:DC:36 Connected: no
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by updating bluez to latest version.

```
https://www.bluez.org/download/

tar xvf bluez-5.66.tar.xz 
cd bluez-5.66
sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev
./configure --enable-library
make
sudo make install

sudo reboot -h now
```